# What's the difference between "inferencing" and "inferring"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences

I have encountered the words "inferencing" and "inferring" in literature on educational research.

Is there a difference in meaning between the words *inferencing* and *inferring*?

Just as an example,

> "The teacher asked the student to **infer** some detail from the text."

If "*inference*" is used instead, does that change the meaning?

Comment: Both lead to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference

Comment: If you added a couple of dictionary definitions, it would correspond more to the site's accepted standards for questions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Dictionaries may take some time, Q&A sites are always ahead. :)

Answer (score 6):

**[inferencing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inferencing)** [ˈɪnfərənsɪŋ] *n* (Linguistics)

> *Psycholinguistics* the practice of inferring the meaning of an unfamiliar word or expression from the meaning of familiar words occurring with it in a context together with one's knowledge of or beliefs about the world

As distinct from [*inferring*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inferring), *inferencing* is a term with a specialized meaning in the field of linguistics, which is now finding wider application in other areas including [artificial intelligence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3101), [graphics](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/Inferencing.htm), high performance computing, control systems, semantic web technologies and several emerging fields as well.

An interesting page from the Open Knowledge Foundation *[About Inferencing](http://blog.okfn.org/2010/08/02/about-inferencing/)* is a good place to start.

Comment: Verbing weirds language.

Comment: @ MT_Head What are you implicationing?

Comment: @MT_Head: It's not so much the verbing, it's the renounification.